# HackerRank: Inserting a Node Into a Sorted Doubly Linked List - Kotlin

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Just wondering if someone would be able to help me on a kotlin implementation of the Hackerrank question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list/problem

I came to the following solution which is only passing 3 out of the 8 tests.

I am confused as to what I am doing incorrectly, as when I searched the internet, I found a Java solution which is very similar - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-value-sorted-way-sorted-doubly-linked-list/

Any help would be appreciated, I'm at a loss with it.

```
fun sortedInsert(llist: DoublyLinkedListNode?, data: Int): DoublyLinkedListNode? {
    val node = DoublyLinkedListNode(data)
    if (llist == null) return node
    
    if (llist.data >= data) {
        node.next = llist
        node.next!!.prev = node
        return node
    }
    
    var current = llist
    while (current?.next != null && current.next!!.data < data) {
        current = current.next
    }
    
    node.next = current?.next
    if (current?.next != null) current.next!!.prev = node
    
    node.prev = current
    current?.next = node
    
    return llist
}
```

Comment: I see [some comments](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list/forum/comments/572442) that the [Kotlin test harness is buggy](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list/forum/comments/470911), but they're a few years old. My solution failed 5/8 cases on submission, but the same algorithm was accepted in Java and JS.

Comment: Looks fine to me at first sight, don't know how hackerrank tests this, so couldn't the error be in your input/output stuff or in DoublyLinkedListNode? On a different note it's worth mentioning that the return value is actually not nullable afaict, so you can drop the question mark, and for while(var x != null) constructs kotlin provides the generateSequence function which allows you to handle that without you having to mutate 'current'. Although it might not be necesarily more readable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HackerRank's test harness appears to be broken for Kotlin, missing a println to separate output for each test case. The reason some pass (including sample tests) is that `t=1` for these, so the bug isn't triggered.

See the problem's [discussion thread](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-into-a-sorted-doubly-linked-list/forum/comments/470911) for more complaints about the issue. Some of the complaints go back 3 years as of December 2021, suggesting that this is not a high priority for HR to fix, if they're even aware of the issue. Furthermore, the problem appears to affect boilerplate in other linked list problems in Kotlin such as [Reverse a Doubly Linked List](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-a-doubly-linked-list/forum).

Here's your code translated into Java 15, which passed HackerRank's judge:

```java
public static DoublyLinkedListNode sortedInsert(
    DoublyLinkedListNode llist, int data
) {
    var node = new DoublyLinkedListNode(data);
    if (llist == null) return node;
    
    if (llist.data >= data) {
        node.next = llist;
        node.next.prev = node;
        return node;
    }
    
    var current = llist;
    while (current.next != null && current.next.data < data) {
        current = current.next;
    }
    
    node.next = current.next;
    if (current.next != null) current.next.prev = node;
    
    node.prev = current;
    current.next = node;
    return llist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I also did this Q and couldn't understand why it wasn't passing all tests.